# Resize dimension of image in client side in React js before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have written an app using mongoose to save my image to mongodb. In my database, I save my image by keeping their url. Then in my react app, I use my data like this:

```
let data = this.state.fetch_data.map(obj => {
      return(
        <img key = {obj._id} src = {obj.filePath}></img>
      );
    });
    return data;
```

But if I want to resize my image base on their width and their height before rendering them in to the screen, how can I do that ?

Comment: Hello I dont think I fully understand what you mean by resize, if you mean compress it should be done on the server before user donwloads the full image, if you mean just change size, why dont you use css.

Comment: I want to resize image base on its width and height. I want to keep the ratio of (width / height)

Comment: This can be done solely by css. Images do keep their aspect ratios by default if you set height or width to specific value, like width: 100% and the other property to auto, height: auto

Comment: I want each image to have maximum height or width equal to an constant number. I will change the width and height base on this number

Comment: `I want each image to have maximum height or width equal to an constant number. I will change the width and height base on this number.` -- So you want the width and height changed to the constant number or you want to change the width and height to something else before render?

Comment: Sorry Iam not following, by any chance can you provide exmaple of what should the result look like?

Comment: It will be something like this: https://gist.github.com/tung2389/33a144e9a4c1da2f13e90683574377ba

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I tought how it should look, I still think it can be done trough css.

Comment: Can you give me some suggestions ?

Answer (score -3):

I found the answer is quite simple. I just need to use this css property:

```
object-fit: contain
```